# Make matching of values on array faster?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, performance, string-matching

This is my code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  devices = ['x', 'y', 'z'];
  device;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.device = 'a';
    for(let i = 0; i<this.devices.length; i++){
      if(this.device == this.devices[i]){
        console.log('Match');
      } else {
        console.log('No matches');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm thinking if my devices list becomes too long then the matching will become significantly slower. So I would like to ask if there is a better, faster and more efficient way of checking if value exists in array.

What I'm trying to implement is attendance.

My app will scan for ids then check if it is in my list.
If there is a match, I will set a boolean to true(for testing purposes)
The said boolean will be on my list.
Something like this

```
device = {
 name: '-K8d34fsd2',
 attendance: true
};
```

Here's what I tried

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  devices = [
    {
      id: 'qwerty123',
      attendance: false
    },
    {
      id: 'zxcvb123',
      attendance: false
    },
  ];
  device;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.device = 'qwerty123';
    // for(let i = 0; i<this.devices.length; i++){
    //   if(this.device == this.devices[i]){
    //     console.log('Match');
    //   } else {
    //     console.log('No matches');
    //   }
    // }

      if(this.devices.id.indexOf(this.device) > -1){
        console.log('Match');
      } else {
        console.log('No matches');
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Use a `Set` instead, and then `mySet.has` is `O(1)`

Comment: Do you mean something like this for js? var numbers = [4, 9, 16, 25, 29];
var first = numbers.find(myFunction);

function myFunction(value, index, array) {
    return value > 18;
}

Comment: No, I mean use an actual `Set`. `new Set(....`

Comment: Can your array be sorted in any way? Is there a sorting that can already be performed to the array before you need to then search it? Searching performance isn't just about the matching function, it is about what to do when something doesn't match - for instance binary sorting and so forth.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Oh I get it, will research more on this. Thank you sir!

Comment: @ChrisCousins I have updated my question, thank you too for the quick response!

Comment: Is your goal just to check whether a `device` exists in `devices` or to create a new `devices` array with updated attendance? @JustineLanceT.Mojal

Comment: My goal is to check whether if the said device is on my list. If yes then set the attendance to true :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some options there.

`Array.indexOf()` which is way better ([slighthly faster using your example on a benchmark](http://jsben.ch/03I5d)) than iterating over the whole array and checking if every element matches the condition.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  devices = ['x', 'y', 'z'];
  device;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.device = 'a';
    if(this.devices.indexOf(this.device) > -1){
        console.log('Match');
    } else {
        console.log('No matches');
    }

  }
}
```

And if you can support ES2016, `Array.includes()` is slightly better than `indexOf()` ([see the same benchmark](http://jsben.ch/03I5d)) and syntatically easier to read.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  devices = ['x', 'y', 'z'];
  device;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.device = 'a';
    if(this.devices.includes(this.device)){
        console.log('Match');
    } else {
        console.log('No matches');
    }

  }
}
```

EDIT: Due to OP's edit on the original question, i'll list the possible ways of doing the search with objects:

## 1 - `for` loop:

```
var test = [{name:'asdfasafdx', attendance: true}, {name:'fdsafdsay', attendance: true}, {name:'sdfasdfasz', attendance: true}];

var device = {name:'fdwoierqea'};

for(let i = 0; i < test.length; i++){
      if(device.name == test[i].name){
        console.log('Match');
      } else {
        console.log('No matches');
      }
}
```

## 2 - `Array.filter()` ([faster](http://jsben.ch/pxMhe))

```
var test = [{name:'asdfasafdx', attendance: true}, {name:'fdsafdsay', attendance: true}, {name:'sdfasdfasz', attendance: true}];

var device = {name:'fdwoierqea'};

if(test.filter(value => value.name === device.name).length > 0){
        console.log('Match')

} else {
        console.log('No matches');
}
```

Comment: Would it be still applicable on my updated question? Thank you for the fast answer! Nice site too :)

Comment: on arrays with objects, how can I use includes and indexOf?

Comment: @JustineLanceT.Mojal About the speed, using a `for` loop instead of a built-in function that seeks for an occurrence, the function will be ever the fast method.

Comment: @JustineLanceT.Mojal Depends on the content of the objects. It is only possible if you have objects with same exact property names. If they have different properties, i think you'll need to go into something similar to a loop.

Comment: Thanks again sir! Will remember that :)

Comment: I"m gonna edit my answer to include your new statements

Comment: Given that the algorithm to find an entry in an unsorted bag of entries would be O(n), regardless of using indexOf or a for loop, how come indexOf is faster? Its algorithm must be the same?

Comment: @VictorAlencarSantos - See [this modified version](http://jsben.ch/IYQRr) of your benchmark. When you take the `console.log` statements out of the `for` loop, the results are much closer, not always in favor of the same option.

Comment: @ConnorsFan thanks for your edit! Seeing your edits, I think the key must be in the `break` statement so the loop stops iterating. Nice one, didn't knew that trick! Updated my description

Comment: I wish I could just spam the upvote button but I cant :(

Comment: Will follow you guys, A BIG THANK YOU! edit: There's no follow button

Comment: @VictorAlencarSantos - In fact, the `break` does not change anything because no match is found. The improvement comes from taking the `console.log` statements out of the loop, and comparing with `===` instead of `==`. With these changes, the `for` loop becomes equivalent to `indexOf` and `includes`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Nice! I just learned one more :) Any tip on why does `console.log` screws up the performance?

Comment: @VictorAlencarSantos - The code inside of the loop does not do much. So adding an extra function call in each iteration is not negligible.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're trying to look up items based on a specific ID, the fastest array is not an array, it's an object:

```
devices = {
   qwerty123: {attendance: true, otherData: "whatever"}, 
   zxcvb123:  {attendance: false, etcetera: "etcetera"}
}
```

Now your "search" is simply a key lookup:

```
devices.querty123  // returns {attendance: true, otherData: "whatever"}
devices.notarealkey // returns undefined

// when searching with a variable:
this.device = 'qwerty123';
devices[this.device] // returns the same as devices.querty123
```

Comment: When searching with a variable, shouldn't we use the `devices[value]` notation?

Comment: Yeah, I should include an example of that as well, thanks @ConnorsFan

Comment: This might be what I need as i'm gonna get the data from firebase using angular fire then save it to a list observable

Answer (score 1):

You can create an updated list of attendance in O(n) [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) using [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

See below for a practical example.

```js
// Input.
const devices = [{id: 'A', attendance: false}, {id: 'B', attendance: false}, {id: 'C', attendance: false}]
const deviceId = 'B'

// Update Device Attendance.
const updateDeviceAttendance = (devices, deviceId) => devices.map(x => {
  if (x.id == deviceId) return {...x, attendance: true}
  return x
})

// Ouput + Proof.
const output = updateDeviceAttendance(devices, deviceId)
console.log(output)
```

Although, O(1) time complexity can be achieved using objects, rather than arrays.

```js
// Input.
const devices = {'A': {attendance: false}, 'B': {attendance: false}, 'C': {attendance: false}}
const deviceId = 'B'

// Update Device Attendance.
const updateDeviceAttendance = (devices, id) => ({...devices, [id]: {id, attendance: true}})

// Ouput + Proof.
const output = updateDeviceAttendance(devices, deviceId)
console.log(output)
```

Comment: Thank you sir! You helped me take the next step:)

Answer (score 0):

While the helpful people of this community typed and submitted an answer, I tried to find one too to contribute.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  devices = [
    {
      id: 'qwerty123',
      attendance: false
    },
    {
      id: 'zxcvb123',
      attendance: false
    },
  ];
  device;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.device = 'qwerty123';

    let result = this.devices.find( device => device.id === this.device);
    console.log(result);
  }
}
```

the find method returns the asked object and if there are none, gives back undefined.
As for speed, I have not tested it yet. I thought others might want to know too.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find